# MVC3 Validation with Entity Framework Model/Database First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to use MVC 3 and the Entity Framework for my application.

The model will be stored in a different assembly to the MVC app.

The choice I'm making is either to use the EF to generate my entities or to use code first.

With code first, I can decorate members with [Required] etc... But how would I go about adding those attributes if EF has generated entities from the DB?

Having EF generate my entities will save a lot of time, but I want MVC to auto populate the validation depending on how I've decorated my members. Does this make sense? If so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In that case, [MetadataTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx) is used. You can combine it with partial classes to achieve desired results

And by the way, in your place i would do more research when deciding between using Database First and Code First designs. That all is not about saving time when generating entities, there's much more difference between those two approaches. For the time saving purpose, you can use [EF Power Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/18/ef-power-tools-ctp1-released.aspx) to generate code first entities from database - simple.

Comment: Thanks, When I do that I get Ambiguous name error. Here is what I've got in my partial class (the entity is called Item in the model):

Comment: [MetadataType(typeof(Item))]
    public partial class Item
    {
        [StringLength(10), Required]
        public string MaterialName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

Comment: paul, the ambiguity 'could' be to do with the pre-existing edmx ef file maybe??

Comment: Generally, naming convention for metadata classes is [className]Metadata. For Item entity, good naming for its metadata would be ItemMetadata. Try this to avoid ambiguous name conflicts

Comment: but that approach makes necessary to edit the class generated by EF, whihc is not good because the changes would be overwritten if the class is re-generated..

Comment: @Diego nonono, you can create another partial class of your entity and put MetadataTypeAttribute on it. This way, you do not touch auto-generated classes

Comment: hey archie! thanks for answering such an old question. I dont think I follow. I have the partial class called ClientControl generated by EF. Then I created a class called ClientControlMetadata with the validations. But to make it work, I had to alter the ClientControl class addinf [MetadataType(typeof(ClientControlMetadata))] on top of it. How can I succedd without this last step of editing the EF class?

Comment: @Diego, on last step, you create another, your own partial class, `public partial class ClientControl` and put attribute on that. That's how partial classes work, they compile into one and attribute gets in its place after compilation

Comment: Don't forget that partials must reside within the same assembly, so in this case, the EDMX project and not the MVC one.

Answer (score 2):

Better than auto generating your entities, I recommend you to use Code First or mapping an existing database to POCO's classes (not generating the entities, just creating them by hand and mapping them to the existing database)

Scottgu wrote about [using EF "Code First" with an existing database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:
In your model template (file with extension model.tt) you can hack this template for generating decorators, in this example I add the [Required] decorator plus an error message

```
var simpleProperties = typeMapper.GetSimpleProperties(entity);
if (simpleProperties.Any())
{
    foreach (var edmProperty in simpleProperties)
    {
        if(!edmProperty.Nullable)
        {#>
[Required(ErrorMessage="<#=String.Format("The field {0} is required",edmProperty.ToString())#>")]<#
        }#>
<#=codeStringGenerator.Property(edmProperty)#><#
    }
}
```

So the result is something like this

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage="The field Id is required")]
    public long Id { get; set; }
```

PS: You can also add the 
`using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` by editing the template.

Hope this can help you up.