# ASP.NET MVC Generated views not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have strange error. 
I made database using SQL Server Management Studio. All Primary Keys, Foreign Keys, Unique set and working.

I imported database into mvc project and generated models, controllers, and views all as stands in this tutorial: [click](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/database-first-development/setting-up-database)

But for unknown reason build in validation works only for foreign keys! Even though that all other validation rules were scaffold-ed by Visual Studio.

Don't know what code I should provide so please free to ask and I will update my question.

eg: Create User:

```
@model magazyn.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>User</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeNo, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeNo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeNo)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactInfo, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactInfo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactInfo)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoleId, "RoleId", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("RoleId", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoleId)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(db.Roles, "Id", "RoleName");
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [UserEditAuth]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Id,EmployeeNo,Name,Surname,ContactInfo,RoleId")] User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(db.Roles, "Id", "RoleName", user.RoleId);
        return View(user);
    }
```

and user entity (generated by entityFramework):

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.DeviceUsages = new HashSet<DeviceUsage>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string ContactInfo { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DeviceUsage> DeviceUsages { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

In this case Only Role is validated because it's foreign key from other table

Comment: Would help have the source code for one of the views (i.e. the Create view), the controller action and one of the entities...

Comment: Ok. Added View, Controller action and entity used in this action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `Database-first` aproach to generate all models. You must extend every EF generated model and then provide `metadata` to annotate every property as Required, MaxLength, etc. You should take a look here:

- [Data Validation in ASP.NET MVC Database First](http://www.elevenwinds.com/data-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-database-first)
- [ASP.NET MVC3 - Data Annotations with EF Database First (ObjectConext, DbContext)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956081/asp-net-mvc3-data-annotations-with-ef-database-first-objectconext-dbcontext)
- [MVC 4 - Database First - Add validation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJhCLhZt_-k)
- [MVC3 Validation with Entity Framework Model/Database First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775071/mvc3-validation-with-entity-framework-model-database-first)

Comment: It's so strange for me.  Why I need to add constraints in DB like not null if I need to do this again in code...

Comment: The View validation works together with Attributes on your model. As you didn't provide everything you need, Model.IsValid will not work properly, because It doesn't know everything about your DB.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that if ET import everything and model.edmx shows where "not null" is everything will be generated. Thanks one more time!